# Do factors in operator polynomial commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, characteristic-polynomial

The problem I am working on asks: Let $A$ be a complex $n \times n$ matrix and suppose $y$ is a nonzero complex $1 \times n$ vector. Show that there is a nonzero polynomial $q(x)$ and an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ such that $y \ q(A)$ is nonzero, and $(y \ q(A)) A = \lambda ( y \ q(A))$.

My strategy: Take the set $(y, yA, yA^2, \dots, yA^n)$. These $n + 1$ vectors thus being linearly dependent, there exist complex coefficients $a_0, \dots, a_n$, not all zero, such that $0 =  \sum_{i=0}^n a_iyA^i = cy(A - \lambda_0I)\dots(A - \lambda_mI)$, where $c$ is a nonzero complex number introduced when factoring the polynomial. My question is: Can I reorder these factors?

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

(By way of additional explanation, the reason I'd want to reorder these factors comes from the rest of my proof: The expression $0 = cy(A - \lambda_0I)\dots(A - \lambda_mI)$ implies that the vector $y$ will be transformed by this series of operators and, somewhere along the way, one of them, say $(A - \lambda_kI)$, must map the input vector to zero. So I let $q(A)$ be the polynomial formed by the factors preceding this factor, i.e. $q(A) = c(A - \lambda_0I)\dots(A - \lambda_{k-1}I)$, which can easily be converted into a polynomial of complex numbers, i.e. the required $q(x)$. Then $y \ q(A) \neq 0$ while $y \ q(A) (A - \lambda_k I) = 0$, which I rearrange to $ (y \ q(A)) A = \lambda_k (y \ q(A))$, as desired. But, what if the first factor $(A - \lambda_0I)$ is the one that maps the vector to zero? Then I have no polynomial constructed from the preceding factors, so I'd like to rearrange the factors so that the one that sends the vector to zero comes later. I also note that I think there are other problems to address with this proof strategy, like what if ALL of the factors map $y$ to zero, but first things first!)

Comment: A constant is a polynomial of degree $0$. But yes, factors commute since the identity commutes with all matrices and $A$ commutes with $A$.

Comment: Ahh!! "A constant is a polynomial of degree 0." Of course! Regarding the other point, thank you so much. I'm prepping for quals, so of course the solution isn't the point, understanding the problem is. Thank you.